# maybe how to Select from select

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help, I'm New to mySQL. I'm wondering how I can write a query to produce the below result:

table1

```
+-----+------+-------+
| id1 |  id2 | col1  |
+-----+------+-------+
| 9   |  1   | foo 1 |
+-----+------+-------+
| 9   |  2   | foo 2 |
+-----+------+-------+
| 9   |  3   | foo 3 |
+-----+------+-------+
| 8   |  4   | foo 4 |
+-----+------+-------+
| 7   |  5   | foo 5 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

table2

```
+-----+------+-------+
| id2 | col2 | col3  |
+-----+------+-------+
|  1  | 2018 | bar 1 |
+-----+------+-------+
|  3  | 2018 | bar 2 |
+-----+------+-------+
|  1  | 2017 | bar 3 |
+-----+------+-------+
|  2  | 2017 | bar 4 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

want to result table1, table2 for `id1 = 9` and `2018`

```
+-----+-------+-------+------+--------+
| id1 |  id2  | col1  | col2 |  col3  |
+-----+-------+-------+------+--------+
|  9  |  1    | foo 1 | 2018 | bar 1  |
+-----+-------+-------+------+--------+
|  9  |  2    | foo 2 | 2018 | "NULL" |
+-----+-------+-------+------+--------+
|  9  |  3    | foo 3 | 2018 | bar 2  |
+-----+-------+-------+------+--------+
```

So far I've tried the following, but haven't gotten it to return the data in the format I'm seeking:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN
    table2 b ON a.id2 = b.id2
WHERE
    a.id1 = 9 AND b.col2 = 2018
```

thanks and really appreciated.

Comment: According your sample data set where id2 = 2 and col2 has 2017 but in your expected output it shows col2 as 2018 where id2 = 2?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'but no luck?' Does the query return an empty set? What data types is used to store table2.col2, is it stored as an integer or as a varchar?

Comment: can you show the output?

Answer (score 4):

You were close. Move the year filter into the join condition:

```
create table table1 (id1 int, id2 int, col1 varchar(20));
insert into table1 (id1, id2, col1) values (9, 1, 'foo 1');
insert into table1 (id1, id2, col1) values (9, 2, 'foo 2');
insert into table1 (id1, id2, col1) values (9, 3, 'foo 3');
insert into table1 (id1, id2, col1) values (8, 4, 'foo 4');
insert into table1 (id1, id2, col1) values (7, 5, 'foo 5');

create table table2 (id2 int, col2 int, col3 varchar(20));
insert into table2 (id2, col2, col3) values (1, 2018, 'bar 1');
insert into table2 (id2, col2, col3) values (3, 2018, 'bar 2');
insert into table2 (id2, col2, col3) values (1, 2017, 'bar 3');
insert into table2 (id2, col2, col3) values (2, 2017, 'bar 4');

SELECT 
    a.id1, a.id2, a.col1, 2018 as col2, b.col3
FROM
    table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id2 = b.id2 and b.col2 = 2018
WHERE
    a.id1 = 9
```

Result:

```
id1        id2          col1              col2  col3                  
-------------------------------------------------------
9          1            foo 1             2018  bar 1                 
9          2            foo 2             2018  <null>                
9          3            foo 3             2018  bar 2
```

Comment: as if I remember this answer from somewhere ;)

Comment: Sorry mate. No plagiarism intended. Made it up from scratch.

Comment: No, no I didn't consider so ... Perhaps we both thought the same thing OK +1

Answer (score 3):

It seems the important point in your question is

using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with  `t1.id2 = t2.id2 and t2.col2 = 2018` Join Condition 
and assigning *the current year* for non-matching values for the year column as in the following SQL :

```
select t1.id1, t1.id2, t1.col1, 
       coalesce(t2.col2,year(now())) as col2, 
       t2.col3
  from table1 t1
  left outer join table2 t2 
  on ( t1.id2 = t2.id2 and t2.col2 = 2018 )
 where t1.id1 = 9 
 order by t1.id2;

 id1    id2  col1   col2    col3

  9      1   foo 1  2018    bar 1
  9      2   foo 2  2018    (null)
  9      3   foo 3  2018    bar 2
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1892d4/34)